# getCssValue (Color) in Hex format in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In the following code I need to print the `color` in `Hex format`.

*First* Print statement is showing value in `RGB` format which is `rgb(102,102,102)`.

The *Second* statement is showing value in `Hex`  which is `#666666`

But I am manually entering the value into the second print statement which is `102,102,102`.

Is there any way to pass the value which I got from the 1st statement (Color) into the second print statement and get result?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Google {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
        String Color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gb_e gb_f gb_g gb_xb']/a")).getCssValue("color");
        System.out.println(Color);
        String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", 102,102,102);
        System.out.println(hex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Way 1: Using StringTokenizer:

```
String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gb_e gb_f gb_g gb_xb']/a")).getCssValue("color");
String s1 = color.substring(4);
color = s1.replace(')', ' ');
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(color);
int r = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken(",").trim());
int g = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken(",").trim());
int b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken(",").trim());
Color c = new Color(r, g, b);
String hex = "#"+Integer.toHexString(c.getRGB()).substring(2);
System.out.println(hex);
```

Way 2:

```
String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gb_e gb_f gb_g gb_xb']/a")).getCssValue("color");
String[] numbers = color.replace("rgb(", "").replace(")", "").split(",");
int r = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0].trim());
int g = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1].trim());
int b = Integer.parseInt(numbers[2].trim());
System.out.println("r: " + r + "g: " + g + "b: " + b);
String hex = "#" + Integer.toHexString(r) + Integer.toHexString(g) + Integer.toHexString(b);
System.out.println(hex);
```

Comment: In "Way 2" you are only using `numbers[0]`, when I believe you should actually be using `numbers[0]`, `numbers[1]` and `numbers[2]`

Comment: Thanks  Victor Moraes to highlight the mistake. Yes, it should be numbers[0], numbers[1] and numbers[2]. I have corrected accordingly.

Comment: "Way 2": The hex values should most likely be padded with leading 0's. I am here because a `driver.getElement().getCssValue("background-color") ` returns and rgba value: rgba(198, 15, 19, 1). DevTools gives a hex value: #c60f13, the above code returns #c6f13. suggest
`String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r,g,b);`

Answer (score 15):

I know this is rather old, but you can get a simpler solution by using `org.openqa.selenium.support.Color`:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.Color;
String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gb_e gb_f gb_g gb_xb']/a")).getCssValue("color");
System.out.println(color);
String hex = Color.fromString(color).asHex();
System.out.println(hex);
```

It gives you a single line solution and even adds leading zeroes when required (something that the previous answers aren't accounting for)

Answer (score 7):

First a quote from Selenium's documentation.

> Get the value of a given CSS property. Color values should be returned
>   as rgba strings, so, for example if the "background-color" property is
>   set as "green" in the HTML source, the returned value will be "rgba(0,
>   255, 0, 1)". Note that shorthand CSS properties (e.g. background,
>   font, border, border-top, margin, margin-top, padding, padding-top,
>   list-style, outline, pause, cue) are not returned, in accordance with
>   the DOM CSS2 specification - you should directly access the longhand
>   properties (e.g. background-color) to access the desired values.

Then this is not a Selenium specific question, this is just a general programming question about how to parse string `rgba(102,102,102)` to three number.

```
// Originally untested code, just the logic.
// Thanks for Ripon Al Wasim's correction.

String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gb_e gb_f gb_g gb_xb']/a")).getCssValue("color");

String[] numbers = color.replace("rgba(", "").replace(")", "").split(",");
int r = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0].trim());
int g = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1].trim());
int b = Integer.parseInt(numbers[2].trim());
System.out.println("r: " + r + "g: " + g + "b: " + b);

String hex = "#" + Integer.toHexString(r) + Integer.toHexString(g) + Integer.toHexString(b);
System.out.println(hex);
```

Comment: user1177636: Your previous code was Integer.toHexString(<String>), but parameter should be integer as Integer.toHexString(<int>)

Answer (score 4):

The code works, but just a little typo. The Color.fromString would be upper case C

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.Color;

String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_value")).getCssValue("color");
System.out.println(color);
String hex = Color.fromString(color).asHex();
System.out.println(hex);
```

Comment: I don't think a single letter typo in my answer would be a reason to add another answer to this. Just edit it, as you did. Plus, when you say "The code works, but just a little typo" it is not clear which code you're talking about. I know you're referring to mine because I received the notification, but for newcomers it might not be that clear. If you insist in providing a separate answer, I'd advise adding a link to mine, for clarity. By the way, now that you edit my answer, yours is just a duplicate of mine with nothing to add (and it's even obsolete, since mine doesn't have typos anymore)

Comment: thanks bro, i couldn't edit or comment because i am under 15

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.Color;

String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_value")).getCssValue("color");
System.out.println(color);
String hex = Color.fromString(color).asHex();
System.out.println(hex);
```

just a simple and sweet code will help you to get a answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).