# How to get element color with Selenium

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to check the color of an element in an html page. 
The color of this element is set with a javascript, look at the image [image]

The element with div-id "Ab_banco_M1T1_switch" can assume 4 values, of course only one of them is displayed according to the value of "val" variable. 
The val variable is set from the server somehow, it seemes the script polls the server every X-seconds and update the value of val.

I've tried to get the color of the element as follow:

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("Ab_banco_M1T1_switch")));

element.getAttribute("background")
element.getAttribute("style")
element.getAttribute("background-color") 
element.getCssValue("style")
element.getCssValue("color")
```

with no success, they return "null" or the backgorund-color of the page.

The only way to get the color is to use the Xpath
    `/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div (for red, if I want the green 
   /html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div)`

But it is not what I want. Indeed, the Xpath localizes the element, but it doesn't tell me if the color displayed is red or another one, I can know it only by looking at the web page.

In other words, I would like to access the  current displayed color as Firebug does, look at the panel on right side, you can see that `element.style ->background-Color = red`.

When I invoke element,`getCssCValue("background-color")` I get the backgorund-color of `#body_right_div`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code looks you are using java

Comment: do u now know how to get the actual rendered color with a font?

Answer (score 17):

You can get the element color(Background color of element) by:

```
element.getCssValue("background-color");
```

You can get the element text/caption color by:

```
element.getCssValue("color");
```

For example if you want to get the background and text color of "Sign in" button for LinkedIn, the code is as follows:

```
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/");
        String buttonColor = driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).getCssValue("background-color");
        String buttonTextColor = driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).getCssValue("color");
        System.out.println("Button color: " + buttonColor);
        System.out.println("Text color " + buttonTextColor);
```

Comment: The above code will return rgb value. If you want to convert to hex, you can go to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668893/getcssvalue-color-in-hex-format-in-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 9):

try this, worked perfect for me:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.Color;

String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_value")).getCssValue("color");
System.out.println(color);
String hex = Color.fromString(color).asHex();
System.out.println(hex);
```

So you can get color using `getCssValue("color");` and  `getCssValue("background-color");`.
However, that would be in RGB, so you need to convert to hex. With hex code you can then compare the value and print it out so that you can see what you are getting after each `getCssValue`.

Comment: I think you help the asker a bit more if you explain your piece of code.

Comment: replied bro: So you can get getCssValue("color"); getCssValue("background-color"); however, that would be in RGB, so you need to convert to hex. with hex code you can then compare the value and print it out so that you can see what you are getting after each getCssValue

Comment: Hello @FaiHasan the above code is not working..throwing error in Color.fromString(color).asHex(); i am using latest Java and selenium..how to change this code to work for current version

Answer (score 0):

With XPath you can try to search by attribute. For example `//div[@style='background: red']`. If you want to get color then for CSS I would use method [getCSSValue()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Try below code public String ColorVerify(String cssSelector, String cssValue)
 {
  /* This method used to verify color code*/
  WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector));
  String colorCode= target.getCssValue(cssValue);
  String hexacolor = Color.fromString(colorCode).asHex();
  return hexacolor; 
 }

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code**

```
public String ColorVerify(String cssSelector, String cssValue)
{
    /* This method used to verify color code*/
    WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector));
    String colorCode= target.getCssValue(cssValue);
    String hexacolor = Color.fromString(colorCode).asHex();
    return hexacolor;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate with selenium the color by Name, you can add this class in your utils files and use it in your tests for color validation.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ColorUtils {

private static ArrayList<ColorName> initColorList() {
    ArrayList<ColorName> colorList = new ArrayList<>();
    colorList.add(new ColorName("AliceBlue", 0xF0, 0xF8, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("AntiqueWhite", 0xFA, 0xEB, 0xD7));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Aqua", 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Aquamarine", 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xD4));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Azure", 0xF0, 0xFF, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Beige", 0xF5, 0xF5, 0xDC));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Bisque", 0xFF, 0xE4, 0xC4));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Black", 0x00, 0x00, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("BlanchedAlmond", 0xFF, 0xEB, 0xCD));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Blue", 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("BlueViolet", 0x8A, 0x2B, 0xE2));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Brown", 0xA5, 0x2A, 0x2A));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("BurlyWood", 0xDE, 0xB8, 0x87));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("CadetBlue", 0x5F, 0x9E, 0xA0));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Chartreuse", 0x7F, 0xFF, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Chocolate", 0xD2, 0x69, 0x1E));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Coral", 0xFF, 0x7F, 0x50));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("CornflowerBlue", 0x64, 0x95, 0xED));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Cornsilk", 0xFF, 0xF8, 0xDC));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Crimson", 0xDC, 0x14, 0x3C));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Cyan", 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkBlue", 0x00, 0x00, 0x8B));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkCyan", 0x00, 0x8B, 0x8B));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkGoldenRod", 0xB8, 0x86, 0x0B));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkGray", 0xA9, 0xA9, 0xA9));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkGreen", 0x00, 0x64, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkKhaki", 0xBD, 0xB7, 0x6B));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkMagenta", 0x8B, 0x00, 0x8B));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkOliveGreen", 0x55, 0x6B, 0x2F));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkOrange", 0xFF, 0x8C, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkOrchid", 0x99, 0x32, 0xCC));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkRed", 0x8B, 0x00, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSalmon", 0xE9, 0x96, 0x7A));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSeaGreen", 0x8F, 0xBC, 0x8F));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSlateBlue", 0x48, 0x3D, 0x8B));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkSlateGray", 0x2F, 0x4F, 0x4F));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkTurquoise", 0x00, 0xCE, 0xD1));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DarkViolet", 0x94, 0x00, 0xD3));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DeepPink", 0xFF, 0x14, 0x93));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DeepSkyBlue", 0x00, 0xBF, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DimGray", 0x69, 0x69, 0x69));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("DodgerBlue", 0x1E, 0x90, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("FireBrick", 0xB2, 0x22, 0x22));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("FloralWhite", 0xFF, 0xFA, 0xF0));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("ForestGreen", 0x22, 0x8B, 0x22));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Fuchsia", 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Gainsboro", 0xDC, 0xDC, 0xDC));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("GhostWhite", 0xF8, 0xF8, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Gold", 0xFF, 0xD7, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("GoldenRod", 0xDA, 0xA5, 0x20));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Gray", 0x80, 0x80, 0x80));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Green", 0x00, 0x80, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("GreenYellow", 0xAD, 0xFF, 0x2F));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("HoneyDew", 0xF0, 0xFF, 0xF0));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("HotPink", 0xFF, 0x69, 0xB4));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("IndianRed", 0xCD, 0x5C, 0x5C));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Indigo", 0x4B, 0x00, 0x82));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Ivory", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF0));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Khaki", 0xF0, 0xE6, 0x8C));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Lavender", 0xE6, 0xE6, 0xFA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LavenderBlush", 0xFF, 0xF0, 0xF5));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LawnGreen", 0x7C, 0xFC, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LemonChiffon", 0xFF, 0xFA, 0xCD));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightBlue", 0xAD, 0xD8, 0xE6));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightCoral", 0xF0, 0x80, 0x80));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightCyan", 0xE0, 0xFF, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightGoldenRodYellow", 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xD2));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightGray", 0xD3, 0xD3, 0xD3));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightGreen", 0x90, 0xEE, 0x90));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightPink", 0xFF, 0xB6, 0xC1));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSalmon", 0xFF, 0xA0, 0x7A));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSeaGreen", 0x20, 0xB2, 0xAA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSkyBlue", 0x87, 0xCE, 0xFA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSlateGray", 0x77, 0x88, 0x99));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightSteelBlue", 0xB0, 0xC4, 0xDE));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LightYellow", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Lime", 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("LimeGreen", 0x32, 0xCD, 0x32));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Linen", 0xFA, 0xF0, 0xE6));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Magenta", 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Maroon", 0x80, 0x00, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumAquaMarine", 0x66, 0xCD, 0xAA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumBlue", 0x00, 0x00, 0xCD));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumOrchid", 0xBA, 0x55, 0xD3));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumPurple", 0x93, 0x70, 0xDB));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumSeaGreen", 0x3C, 0xB3, 0x71));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumSlateBlue", 0x7B, 0x68, 0xEE));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumSpringGreen", 0x00, 0xFA, 0x9A));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumTurquoise", 0x48, 0xD1, 0xCC));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MediumVioletRed", 0xC7, 0x15, 0x85));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MidnightBlue", 0x19, 0x19, 0x70));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MintCream", 0xF5, 0xFF, 0xFA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("MistyRose", 0xFF, 0xE4, 0xE1));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Moccasin", 0xFF, 0xE4, 0xB5));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("NavajoWhite", 0xFF, 0xDE, 0xAD));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Navy", 0x00, 0x00, 0x80));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("OldLace", 0xFD, 0xF5, 0xE6));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Olive", 0x80, 0x80, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("OliveDrab", 0x6B, 0x8E, 0x23));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Orange", 0xFF, 0xA5, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("OrangeRed", 0xFF, 0x45, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Orchid", 0xDA, 0x70, 0xD6));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleGoldenRod", 0xEE, 0xE8, 0xAA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleGreen", 0x98, 0xFB, 0x98));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleTurquoise", 0xAF, 0xEE, 0xEE));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("PaleVioletRed", 0xDB, 0x70, 0x93));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("PapayaWhip", 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xD5));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("PeachPuff", 0xFF, 0xDA, 0xB9));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Peru", 0xCD, 0x85, 0x3F));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Pink", 0xFF, 0xC0, 0xCB));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Plum", 0xDD, 0xA0, 0xDD));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("PowderBlue", 0xB0, 0xE0, 0xE6));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Purple", 0x80, 0x00, 0x80));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Red", 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("RosyBrown", 0xBC, 0x8F, 0x8F));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("RoyalBlue", 0x41, 0x69, 0xE1));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SaddleBrown", 0x8B, 0x45, 0x13));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Salmon", 0xFA, 0x80, 0x72));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SandyBrown", 0xF4, 0xA4, 0x60));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SeaGreen", 0x2E, 0x8B, 0x57));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SeaShell", 0xFF, 0xF5, 0xEE));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Sienna", 0xA0, 0x52, 0x2D));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Silver", 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SkyBlue", 0x87, 0xCE, 0xEB));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SlateBlue", 0x6A, 0x5A, 0xCD));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SlateGray", 0x70, 0x80, 0x90));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Snow", 0xFF, 0xFA, 0xFA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SpringGreen", 0x00, 0xFF, 0x7F));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("SteelBlue", 0x46, 0x82, 0xB4));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Tan", 0xD2, 0xB4, 0x8C));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Teal", 0x00, 0x80, 0x80));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Thistle", 0xD8, 0xBF, 0xD8));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Tomato", 0xFF, 0x63, 0x47));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Turquoise", 0x40, 0xE0, 0xD0));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Violet", 0xEE, 0x82, 0xEE));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Wheat", 0xF5, 0xDE, 0xB3));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("White", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("WhiteSmoke", 0xF5, 0xF5, 0xF5));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Yellow", 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("YellowGreen", 0x9A, 0xCD, 0x32));
    return colorList;
}

public static String getColorNameFromRgb(int r, int g, int b) {
    ArrayList<ColorName> colorList = initColorList();
    ColorName closestMatch = null;
    int minMSE = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int mse;
    for (ColorName c : colorList) {
        mse = c.computeMSE(r, g, b);
        if (mse < minMSE) {
            minMSE = mse;
            closestMatch = c;
        }
    }

    if (closestMatch != null) {
        return closestMatch.getName();
    } else {
        return "No matched color name.";
    }
}

public static String getColorNameFromColor(Color color) {
    return getColorNameFromRgb(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(),
            color.getBlue());
}

public static Color stringToColor(final String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return Color.black;
    }
    try {
        return Color.decode(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        try {
            final Field f = Color.class.getField(value);
            return (Color) f.get(null);
        } catch (Exception ce) {
            return Color.black;
        }
    }
}

public static class ColorName {
    public int r, g, b;
    public String name;

public ColorName(String name, int r, int g, int b) {
    this.r = r;
    this.g = g;
    this.b = b;
    this.name = name;
}

public int computeMSE(int pixR, int pixG, int pixB) {
    return ((pixR - r) * (pixR - r) + (pixG - g) * (pixG - g) + (pixB - b)
            * (pixB - b)) / 3;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

}
}`

An example of the usage of this class.

```
public String getElementColor(WebElement element) {

    String color = element.getCssValue("color");
    String hex = Color.fromString(color).asHex();
    java.awt.Color c = stringToColor(hex);
    return getColorNameFromColor(c);
}
```