# Selenium state of button to be clicked

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, python-3.6

I have a site which is populated from a database. I want to access the pages in Selenium. The number pages associated with a particular topic is variable.

Using Selenium I am clicking through successive pages using a line like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="mainContent"]/
                                     div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/
                                     div[3]/div[2]""").click()
```

This works successfully.

However I would like to detect when the element I am clicking (a next button) is "greyed" out rather than having to predict how many pages are available.

Currently I am using a block of code inside a for loop with a counter for the number of available pages.

EDIT: The page element has the word Inactive added when it is "greyed out" as in

```
<div class="paginationBtn paginationNextContainer inactive"><div class="icn chevron-left"></div><div class="visuallyHidden">Previous</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your button is changing its color on click, it's associated with CSS attribute.

I advise to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220575/how-to-get-element-color-with-selenium) to learn the subject. For your case, I advise you to develop a method to get the button color value before and after, as your script should operate accordingly.