# In my application, i need to validate Pass or Fail icon in Selenium webdriver

Tags: html, css, selenium

This is the html on the application

```
 div id="StatusCircle" style="float: right; width: 50px; height: 50px;-webkit-border-radius: 25px;-moz-border-radius: 25px;border-radius: 25px;background: RED;" - this is for Fail

 div id="StatusCircle" style="float: right; width: 50px; height: 50px;-webkit-border-radius: 25px;-moz-border-radius: 25px;border-radius: 25px;background: GREEN;" - this is for Pass
```

i am able to get

```
  .//*[@id='MainContent']/a[2]/div/div/div[@id='StatusCircle']
```

but how to get its Red or Green.

Comment: you can validate the attribute using selenium , getting the value of the attribute background color so that it can be validated as pass for green and red for fail

Comment: Aside: why do you have an xpath with two ids? Just id StatusCircle should be enough since ids are supposed to be unique

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the color background using 'getCssValue()' that returns rgb value and than convert to Hex value to check.

More information:

[getCssValue (Color) in Hex format in Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668893/getcssvalue-color-in-hex-format-in-selenium-webdriver)

[Selenium Webdriver - Get Background color of an element in Hex - Example](http://testautomationarchives.blogspot.com.br/2013/12/selenium-webdriver-get-background-color.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
IWebElement statusElement = driver.FindElement(By....);
string statusAttribute = statusElement.GetAttribute("style");
if (statusAttribute.Contains("RED"))
{
  //Status is Fail
}
else if (statusAttribute.Contains("GREEN"))
{
    //Status is Fail
}
```